# Define routine task at specific times

Tags: java

currently Im using Java timer to repeat a task, but currently, I only can specify the time like every 30 seconds ... by using

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

}
  }, 30 * 1000, 30 * 1000);
```

Yet what I really want is this constrain:

The task will be run every HH:MM,with MM (Minute) = 00 and HH (Hour) can be 10, 15, 19 ...

I hope that I described the problem clear enough, like every HH o'clock, the task will be run.

I found that it is impossible to do with Timer if I don't start the timer at HH:00 o'clock and the interval will be set to 6000.
I want to use it multiples times everyday (Like every hour)

Thank you very much.

Comment: I woud use threads and date class.

Comment: You can use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), or you can use the quartz inputs to write your own job scheduler.

Comment: Do you want to start at every 00 minute of every Hour?

Comment: yes, that's what I want :)

Answer (score 4):

You could create a new Date object with your target time, then convert it to system time and substract it from `System.currentTimeMillis()` and sleep for that many ms

As in:

```
Date alarm = DateFormat.parse(___your date here___);
long msToSleep = alarm.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
// Your provided code to sleep for msToSleep ms
```

Comment: This is perfect solution!

Comment: but this only can be used for one specific everyday, right ? I need to use it multiple times per day, almost every hour :P ()My bad, the question wasn;t clear enough.

Comment: Well, if you're going to do this every hour, then consider instead `schedule(java.util.TimerTask, java.util.Date, long)` in [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use below code to run TimerTask every hours HH:00:-
Timer timer = new Timer();
        Calendar cd = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date dt = cd.getTime();
        long mmss = dt.getMinutes() * 60 + dt.getSeconds();
        long remTime = 60 * 60 * 60 - mmss;

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, remTime * 1000, 60*60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I tested it but it didn't work when the clock changes to new hour (the computer's clock)

Answer (score 1):

You can define start time of Timer by `Calendar`. The timer will start on `Calendar` time,

```
  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal.set(today.get(Calendar.YEAR),today.get(Calendar.MONTH),
          today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), today.get(Calendar.HOUR),
                             00);
                              |_ Here set the start minutes at 00

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("beep");
        }
    }, startCal.getTime(), 30 * 1000);
         |
         |_ It will start on every 00 minutes of
```

Comment: Can you please check it again, it prints the "beep" message continuously, i guess that is not what we want to archive

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
private static final int SLEEP_TIME=1000;//your sleep time (mili second)
public void Routine(){
    while(true){
        try {
            //your code goes here
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            if(someCondition)
               break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```